# Center text in an HTML footer

Tags: html, css

I've got a footer, and I would like to align the text (phone numbers, address, ect) to all be on the same few lines, and the information to be displayed horizonally. How would I do this with CSS, or will I need to use something else? Here's my HTML.

(Not the &nbsp was used to align the phone numbers. And here's the CSS.

```css
footer {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.phone {
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.address {
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="phone">
    Phone: (###) ###-####<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(###) ###-####
  </div>
  <div class="address">
    Address: 1234 Road Name Hwy<br> City, State 12345
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use display flex and align-items:center for middle.. remove those br tag

```css
  footer {
display:flex;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid white;
justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
 

}
 
 .phone {
   color: darkgrey;
   font-size: 14px;
margin:auto;
 }
 
 .address {
   color: darkgrey;
   font-size: 14px;
 margin:auto;
 }
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="phone"> 
    Phone: (###) ###-####(###) ###-####
    </div>
    <div class="address">
    Address: 1234 Road Name Hwy City, State 12345
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Honestly, not really sure why i though putting the two numbers below each other was a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the phone and address divs to `inline-block` then use `text-align: center` on the footer. Then reset `text-align: left` on the phone and address divs if you don't want that text centered.

```css
 footer {
   display: block;
   background-color: black;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   border-top: 1px solid white;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .phone {
   color: darkgrey;
   font-size: 14px;
 }
 .address {
   color: darkgrey;
   font-size: 14px;
 }
 .address, .phone {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="phone"> 
    Phone: (###) ###-####<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(###) ###-####
    </div>
    <div class="address">
    Address: 1234 Road Name Hwy<br> City, State 12345
    </div>
</footer>
```

You can also use `display: flex; justify-content: center;` on the footer.

```css
 footer {
   display: block;
   background-color: black;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   border-top: 1px solid white;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
 }
 
 .phone {
   color: darkgrey;
   font-size: 14px;
 }
 
 .address {
   color: darkgrey;
   font-size: 14px;
 }
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="phone"> 
    Phone: (###) ###-####<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(###) ###-####
    </div>
    <div class="address">
    Address: 1234 Road Name Hwy<br> City, State 12345
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: The question wasn't really clear enough abut what should be on what lines, but I do think this is a good answer.  That said, OP should make sure they understand what `br` and `&nbsp;` actually do and when/why one would apply CSS to individual div's.  I'm not sure OP necessarily even wants to have phone and address in different div objects with different CSS.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel yeah, no clue what they're trying to do with all those `&nbsp;`'s. I'm guessing they are trying to emulate `text-align: right` on the phone div?

Comment: Yea sorry about the wording. My descriptive skills are definitely sub par. But thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `display: inline-block` to the `phone` and `address` elements:

https://codepen.io/dreiv/pen/dWoZXr?editors=1100

naturally div's extend for the full width of the parent element they are set into, but in this case we would need them to take just the space they occupy, and flow like inline elements.